# Azure LogicApp runs webjob and send email

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-logic-apps

I want to create an `Azure LogicApps` that has to launch and verify the status of a `webjob`. This is because I want to take an action if the `webjob` finishes its activities with an error and, in this case, the `LogicApps` has to send an email with an alert and restart the `webjob`.

I have tried to find some documentation about it on `LogicApps` site and in the editor but I can't find any connectors.

Any ideas, documentation or samples? Thank you

Comment: you can start your webjob using an http action. Is it a C# webjob or just a script ?

Comment: It is a C# webjob. How can I use an `http action`? I see that every `webjob` has a `webhook` (with username and password): can I use it? Thanks

Comment: Yeah you can use it to trigger your webjob. Are you using the webjob sdk ? You can handle sending email using it also

Comment: Ok but how can I receive the result of the `webapi` and then decide what I have to do?

Comment: which web api ? the webjob status from kudu ?

Comment: Yes! Do the `webhook` send any update? If yes, how can I check it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought my way could meet your requirements.

You could use a HTTP trigger to get the **latest_run** property with **GET** method. The URI would look something like `https://{webapp-name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/{webjob-name}/`. Then click **advanced options**, choose **Basic** Authentication. You could get username and password from publish profile or go to `Webjobs` on the **Kudu** then click the `Properties`. The trigger would be like the pic shows.

[image]

Then add a compose action, use `HTTP Body` as `Inputs`. After this , you could judge the status property. The whole flow would be like the below pic.

[image]

**Note:when you use condition to judge status, you need to switch Designer to Code view, then change the value. The value should be `"@outputs('Compose')['latest_run']['status']".`** Or you could refer my code view page.

[image]

Hope this could help you , If you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you! Your post is very useful. I'm trying to understand where I can find `latest_run` and `status` . The `componse` output is a json like ```{ "status": "Running", "detailed_status": "bacaf4 - Running\r\n", "log_url": "", "name": "PublishCollections", "run_command": "PublishCollections.exe", "url": "", "extra_info_url": "", "type": "continuous", "error": null, "using_sdk": true, "settings": {} }```

Comment: Also, how can I stop a `webjob`? Thank you in advance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54186509/can-a-azure-logicapps-stop-a-webjob

Comment: About how to stop, you could refer to this wiki.https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#stop-a-continuous-job

Comment: And continuous webjob detail should be like this.https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#get-a-specific-continuous-job-by-name  You wouldn't see latest_run , you could get status directly.