# Can a Azure LogicApps stop a webjob?

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-logic-apps

`Azure LogicApps` time! In my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54169693/azure-logicapp-runs-webjob-and-send-email) my problem was to understand how to run a `webjob`. My problem is: how can I stop a `webjob`?

In another posts in Stackoverflow, people send a `DELETE` request to stop a webjob like

```
$username = $website.PublishingUsername
$password = $website.PublishingPassword
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))
$ps = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$apiBaseUrl/processes" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method GET    
$id = $($ps | where {$_.name -eq $jobname} ).id
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$apiBaseUrl/processes/$id" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method DELETE    
write-host "killed process $id"
```

I sent just a `DELETE` request and the webjob disappeared. Basically, it was deleted.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure/stop-azurewebsitejob?view=azuresmps-4.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still could use **HTTP** trigger or action to request a **Post** action. But You need to pay attention to one thing, the **Webjob API** only support to stop **continuous** Webjob. So if yours is continuous, you could achieve your purpose.

And this is my test pic.
[image]
[image]

And the WebJob API still support other request action, about details you could refer to this **[wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#stop-a-continuous-job)**.

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable/enable a Logic App with Powershell:

```
# Action disable
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName RESOURCEGROUPNAME -ResourceType Microsoft.Logic/workflows -ResourceName RESOURCENAME -Action disable -ApiVersion 2016-06-01 -Force

# Action enable
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName RESOURCEGROUPNAME -ResourceType Microsoft.Logic/workflows -ResourceName RESOURCENAME -Action enable -ApiVersion 2016-06-01 -Force
```

Comment: It is possible to start or stop `webjobs` using their url. For example to start a webjob you can call `POST /api/continuouswebjobs/{job name}/start` or to stop `POST /api/continuouswebjobs/{job name}/stop`. I found this document quite useful http://puresourcecode.com/dotnet/post/2019/01/15/azure-webjobs-api4

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to use the `Azure Resource Manager` connector, and "Invoke resource operation` operation to stop a webjob.